# c# SharePoint combine multiple ListItemCollection into one

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml, sharepoint-online

I have a list with more than 5000 items on Sharepoint Online Site. Before the list reached 5000 items, I've used the following snippet to get all items:

```
var camlquery = new CamlQuery();
camlquery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                        <ViewFields>
                            <FieldRef Name='OppId' />
                        </ViewFields>
                        <Query>
                            <QueryOptions>
                                <ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
                            </QueryOptions>
                        </Query>
                    </View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = _currentList.GetItems(camlquery);
_clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(item => item["OppId"], item => item.Id));
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now I got in this nasty situation where I have more than 5000 items. Normally this is not an problem. I've managed it before in powershell by paging through the results.

In this case I'm using [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitemcollection.aspx) and add items to the collection with the function `GetItems(camlquery)`. When I try adding additional items from another 'page' it seems not to work.

I tried to loop through the items and add these to the ListItemCollection. But there is no Add or Insert function available.

```
foreach (ListItem myListItem in listItems2)
{
     listItems.Add(myListItem);         
}
```

I need to return one ListItemCollection with more than 5000 items.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to get all items by using `IList<ListItem>` to collect all the objects of type `ListItem` from the `ListItemCollection`.

```
IList<ListItem> listItemsAll = new List<ListItem>();
// Loop through pages of list items
//... Getting all items

foreach (ListItem myListItem in listItems)
{
    listItemsAll.Add(myListItem);
}
// End Loop
return listItemsAll;
```

In this case I return a List but I only needed to change the type of list from `ListItemCollection` to `IList<ListItem>`. Everythings works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Convert listItems and listItems2 to Datatable and then copy rows of datatable1 to datatable2

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable1.Rows) {
    dataTable2.Rows.Add(dr);
```

}